# How to copy list of database object in different type of list object?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to copy list of one database object in different type of list object. 
Is there any short and efficient way to do that?

```
public class User
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   public string LastName { get; set; }

   public string Address { get; set; }

   public int MobileNo { get; set; }

}


public Username
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}


List<User> user = new List<User>();
List<Username> nameList = new List<Name>();

user = db.User();

foreach(var user in user)
{
  Username name = new Name();
  name.Name = user.UserName;

  nameList.Add(name);
}
```

Is it possible to copy one list into another without looping?

Comment: Answered in many places already. Try using AutoMapper or EmitMapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping is really the only answer here I am afraid. There are various ways of doing it instead of a basic `for loop` with some syntactic sugar however that's pretty much it. You could look into a mapping library such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) but that still requires configuration.

Alternatives include LINQ, or just writing a mapping method

```
var mapped = collection.Select(c => new Username() { Name = c.Username }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Projection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693038.aspx) :

```
nameList  = user.Select(u => u.UserName).ToList();
```